# Use Springs flash scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller having two methods.

First method is to fetch results from the database which has a link . I am not directly exposing the link as i dont want any user to modify the link and submit the request.

When the user clicks on the link I will get the index of the link in the search results list back in the second method and I want the search results to be available in the second method. I tried using `FlashMap` and `RequestAttributes` but I am losing the data.

I am using Thymleaf with spring boot 1.5.3. Below is sample code.

```
class MyObject {

    int id;
    String docId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
public class DataController{

    @Autowired
    DataService dataService.

    @RequestMapping("/search" method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String fetchData(Model model,RequestAttributes rs){
        List<MyObject> objectList=dataService.fetchData();
        rs.addFlashAttributes("list",dataService.fetchData());
        return VIEW_NAME;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/download/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String downloadData(@PathVariable int id,RequestAttributes rs){
        rs.getFlashAttribute("list").get(id);
        //some logic
    }
}
```

I get a null pointer exception for get(id) as I am not able to get the list from which I added in method 1.

Comment: Flash attributes are useful for redirects after processing. They aren't meant (or useable) for this use case. IMHO you should just provide a link with an ID. Trying to do it by index is dangerous (what would happen if in between requests a record was inserted or deleted). You can always use an encoded ID instead.

Comment: I should be more clear on the ID part. Basically it is the index in the list that I am after. I get the index basing on what the user clicks and I want to retrieve the object in the list that i had when i fetched from the database. I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: Storing the lists in between the requests is, from a memory perspective, generally not a smart thing to do. Imagine 100 users holding the whole content of the DB in memory... It might sound like a good idea for a single users but this won't really scale (depending on the size of your data). And as stated the flash attributes are only useful in a redirect scenario, they survive a single request (and after that are part of the model).

Comment: I need to store the list only for one subsequent request. If I am not supposed to do so the other alternative for me is to query the database again which implies I have to do the same query once again and see that the input I received was actually part of the search results earlier. Is there any other way of doing this ? Also the list is not going to be huge. It will be a maximum of 50 after say 4 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are entering second method that is second request. All request scope data (including request attributes) set in first call will be lost.
The solution might be to use session, but for each user you'll store list of some objects that might be pretty big. I would think on other solution: to have your ids to DB ids mapping in one place (data service).

Comment: But isn't that what Flash scope means. As per documentation it says it will be stored for the next request..[http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes] document link

Comment: It works only for redirect case only and removed after. Will not work in case of two completely independent requests.